# Не понятно про Policy в Laravel

Tags: laravel

В контроллере Task Controller в методе

```
public function create()
    {
        $this->authorize('create', auth()->user()); 
}
```

проверяется разрешение выполнить действие.

При этом есть 2 политики: Task Policy и UserPolicy с одинаковыми методами :

```
public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->isAdmin();
    }
```

Вопрос:  почему для Task Controller проверка идет в User Policy, а не в TaskPolicy? Кто подскажет что я упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel не связывает контроллер с политиками, как вы подумали. Он связывает модель с политикой. Читаем "[Policy Auto-Discovery](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#policy-auto-discovery)" и "[Actions That Don't Require Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#controller-actions-that-dont-require-models)". После полученных знаний становится понятно, что не нужно указывать пользователя. Нужно указывать имя класса для которого нужна проверка:

```
$this->authorize('create', Task::class);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже дошел до этого понимания методом "тыка". В blade шаблонах  вот так: @can(create, App\Models\Task::class) Честно говоря очень не интуитивно реализовано.